# How to play a sound after script finishes?

Tags: scripting, audio

Is there a way to play a sound after a script finishes ? For scripts taking between 30min and many hours (like the delaunay triangulation one from doomlysz), it's good to not have to check every 10 min if the job is done or not.

Comment: You could edit the scripts you use to play a sound (or run custom operator which plays the sound). See [this post on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) for playing audio in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could play a MP3 file using the [aud module](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/aud.html)

```
import aud
import time

sound = aud.Factory.file(pathToMP3 )
device = aud.device()
handle = device.play(sound)
# omit this to play full sound file
time.sleep(5) 
handle.stop()
```

Alternatively you could launch any external application as described here: [Run an external application with the bge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/run-an-external-application-with-the-bge/3058#3058)

Comment: It gives me this error today: AttributeError: module 'aud' has no attribute 'Factory'

Comment: Hm, the current version should stil support this https://docs.blender.org/api/current/aud.html you could post a new question for your 2.8? Version

Comment: Yes, I know. Strange. Maybe my installation is broken somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using winsound. As it is for windows, it is not available to all blender user.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#module-winsound

I do a distinctive beep like this. I don't have to search for an suitable mp3.

```
import winsound

frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
duration = 1000  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

I got it from this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537481/python-making-a-beep-noise/45079462