# How to run a script when when baking is finished?

Tags: scripting, baking

I need sort of an alarm script that will play a loud sound when baking has finished. How can I get such a  script to run when baking is complete?

Comment: Here is a script that play or shutdown your computer at the end of a render. I think it's a good start

Comment: http://www.blendernation.com/2014/05/11/add-on-alarm-and-shutdown-at-render-completion/ ... sorry I forgot to put the link :S

Answer (score 1):

Blender currently supports only [callbacks](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.60/Python) for these events:

- frame_change_pre, frame_change_post
- render_pre, render_post
- render_stats
- load_pre, load_post
- save_pre, save_post

The simplest thing you could do is invoke the appropriate bake operator by a script (the python call is displayed when the mouse pointer is over the back button).

Create a python script e.g.:

```
bpy.ops.fluid.bake()
```

and add the code to play a sound from [How to play a sound after script finishes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/how-to-play-a-sound-after-script-finishes/5645#5645)